# Can you change to natural touchpad scrolling with command line?

Tags: touchpad

I am writing an `ansible` script to bootstrap a development machine. First thing I noticed was that the touchpad scrolls in the unnatural direction.

How can you change this setting with if I'm not able to use the graphical interface?

Comment: What do you mean by "unnatural direction"? Has it weird behaviours when scrolling, like jumping lines or something similar? If so, it might be a video driver issue. Can you please provide more info on the problem?

Comment: Think of a piece of paper on a smooth surface, put two fingers on it and scroll it so you see the very bottom. That is the natural direction.

Comment: I knew natural direction, just never heard of "unnatural" one! :)

Comment: Aha, the unnatural direction could be going left or going right. In this case the unnatural direction is swiping up makes the page move higher

Comment: Does your script have to work for all flavours?

Comment: Nope all other flavours are junk except Debian

Answer (score 6):

To turn on "natural scrolling" for the touchpad run the following:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad natural-scroll true
```

To do the same for the mouse run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse natural-scroll true
```

If you wish to deactivate it again just run the same but change the `true` to `false`.

Comment: very cool! I just tested this and it works for me

Comment: Note, this assumes a gnome-based environment, and won't work on KDE, nor any graphical environment that doesn't use the glib library.

Comment: @Braiam: What other official flavours will this not work for?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and all I receive is `No such schema 'org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad'`